# Como duplicar visualização de elementos HTML

Tags: javascript, classes, div, condição, img

Tenho 5 imagens, sendo que 3 delas tem a mesma `class` sendo exibidas na `div` A.

```
<div id='A'>

   <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/09.jpg" class="figura" />

   <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/10.jpg" class="foto" />

   <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/11.jpg" class="foto" />

   <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/12.jpg" class="foto" />

   <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/13.jpg" class="figura" />

</div>

<div id='B'>
   ...
</div>
```

Com base nessa lógica, quero criar um Script com condição `if` para comparar as `class='foto'`. Se as incidências forem idênticas, então mostrar também na `div` B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```js
// procura as imagens todas
var imagens = document.querySelectorAll('#A img');
var obj = {};

// percorre as imagens
for (var i = 0, l = imagens.length; i < l; i++) {
    var img = imagens[i];
    var classes = img.className.split(' '); // para casos onde há mais que uma classe
    classes.forEach(function(classe) {
        if (!obj[classe]) obj[classe] = []; // inicia a array dessa classe no objeto que separa as classes
        if (obj[classe].indexOf(img) == -1) obj[classe].push(img);
    });
}
var aCopiar = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(imgs, classe) {
    // lógica para só passar images que aparecem mais que uma vez
 if (obj[classe].length > 2) return imgs.concat(obj[classe]);
 else return imgs;
}, []).filter(function(el, i, arr) {
    return arr.indexOf(el) == i;
});

console.log(aCopiar)

var divB = document.getElementById('B');
aCopiar.forEach(function(img) {
    divB.appendChild(img.cloneNode());
});
```

```css
#A {
  display: none;
  /* Só para o exemplo */
}
```

```html
<div id='A'>
  <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/09.jpg" class="figura" />
  <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/10.jpg" class="foto" />
  <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/11.jpg" class="foto" />
  <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/12.jpg" class="foto" />
  <img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/13.jpg" class="figura" />
</div>

<div id='B'></div>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1x6Lu4xc/1